# ¿Cuáles son los hitos de esta comunidad en cuanto a proyección mediática?

Tags: discusión, promoción-de-la-comunidad

Hoy [nos avisó Charlie](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44744416#44744416) de que [Alfred López](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/19503/alfred-l%C3%B3pez) se ha registrado en el sitio. Se trata del autor del famoso blog [Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/). Tras la alegría inicial, y hablando del tema, se nos ocurrió recopilar los hitos que ha conseguido esta comunidad a lo largo de los años. En particular, en qué ocasiones ha tenido proyección mediática,  alguna interacción con personas renombradas, apariciones en sitios web famosos, etc.

Listemos pues estos hitos :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 2012

- 26 de noviembre. Se registra en el sitio [Chewie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1149/chewie), el creador de [DIRAE](https://dirae.es).

#### 2016

- 21 de junio. [Arturo Pérez-Reverte media en unas dudas](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/745330797058605056) al hilo de la pregunta [¿Es correcto mantener “de” y “el” separados en algún caso?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17118/1674), como se recoge en la [respuesta de Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17172/1674).

#### 2017

- 26 de octubre. La pregunta [¿Por qué "duro" en España significa "dinero"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22935/12637) llega a [portada de Menéame](https://www.meneame.net/m/Etimologia/origen-duro-como-moneda-5-pesetas).

#### 2018

- 1 de mayo. La pregunta [¿Cómo se convirtió el verbo “torturar” en el verbo “trabajar”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26053/1674) sube hasta la [página prinicipal de Menéame](https://www.meneame.net/m/cultura/como-convirtio-verbo-torturar-verbo-trabajar) y permanece allí unas horas.
- 18 de mayo. Una estudiante de filología hispánica de Lituania nos comenta (vía email) que utiliza la pregunta [¿Se dice “me alegro que” o “me alegro de que”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16324/1674) para su trabajo de final de carrera.
- 22 de mayo. Alfred López, autor del blog [*Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe*](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/), se registra en el sitio ([con este usuario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/19503/alfred-l%C3%B3pez)).

---

Mención e hilo aparte merecen los cambios en el DLE que la RAE ha hecho a petición nuestra. Tanto las aceptadas como las pendientes pueden consultarse en: [¿Qué propuestas de modificación del DLE nos ha admitido a trámite la RAE?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3191)

Comment: Parece que lirondos... https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1275/zeravla

Comment: Pues, entonces, creo que estaré muy a la expectativa de alguna pregunta llamativa, para enviarla a Menéame.