# ¿Qué propuestas de modificación del DLE nos ha admitido a trámite la RAE?

Tags: discusión, petición-de-funcionalidad

Como entusiastas que somos del idioma español, y como consecuencia de las numerosas preguntas y respuestas que se generan en el sitio principal, o incluso de charlas en [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), a veces nos hemos dado cuenta de pequeñas inexactitudes o puntos de mejora en el DLE.

Para poder hacer un seguimiento de todas esas propuestas de mejora que han partido de este sitio, me gustaría tener esta pregunta en la cual podríamos poner cada propuesta admitida a trámite en una respuesta. Cada cierto tiempo le haríamos un seguimiento y, si alguna vez llegamos a ver un cambio hecho realidad, marcaríamos la respuesta con el tag de [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Así pues, os pido que tiremos de memoria para recopilar los cambios que hemos conseguido proponer hasta ahora (por ejemplo, aquellos solicitados a través de su [formulario](https://www.rae.es/formulario/unidrae)), y que los cambios que nos admitan a trámite en un futuro los vayamos añadiendo aquí también.

¿Qué propuestas de modificación del DLE nos ha admitido la RAE?

Comment: En [¿Cuáles son los hitos de esta comunidad en cuanto a proyección mediática?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2940/1674) ya listamos algunos. Me parece bien que lo pongamos en una publicación aparte, para darle mayor visibilidad a semejantes hitos :)

Comment: @fedorqui cierto, de hecho venía de leer esa publicación, se me olvidó añadir en la pregunta que quería sacar aparte estos hitos para tenerlos más controlados.

Comment: @walen tienes razón, me refería a "admitida a trámite". Básicamente, que en algún momento nos hayan dicho que la propuesta tiene sentido y que la van a revisar. He modificado la pregunta para reflejar eso.

Comment: @Charlie Otra posible sugerencia para la RAE  es aclarar la definición de *europeo* de acuerdo con lo que recoge Rodrigo en su respuesta a https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22966/demonyms-in-spanish-for-the-planets-of-the-solar-system/22969#22969

Comment: @saki y a quien le interese: las propuestas al DLE las puede hacer cualquiera haciendo uso de [su formulario online](https://www.rae.es/formulario/unidrae). Si veis que de algún post se puede formular una propuesta, como estáis comentando, podéis proceder y cuando la RAE os conteste podéis añadir aquí una respuesta nueva.

Comment: No parece que en [la versión 23.4](https://www.rae.es/noticia/la-actualizacion-234-del-diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola-incorporara-2557-novedades-en-su) hayan admitido ninguna de nuestras propuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> En esta respuesta iremos recopilando todas aquellas propuestas que finalmente han encontrado su lugar en el DLE, es decir, las  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) :)

---

En *[Is the phrase "Me siento mal" grammatically correct in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22264/12637)* advertimos a la RAE de que en la definición de *[mal<sup>2</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NyEeGCh)* faltaba una definición paralela a la de *[bien](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5TkGdE0)* como "con buena salud". La RAE nos agradeció la observación y la remitió al Instituto de Lexicografía, aclarando que esa definición sí se encontraba en el *Diccionario del estudiante*, de 2011.

En la versión 23.2 del DLE, de diciembre de 2018, ya se puede leer la acepción "con mala salud" en la mencionada entrada para *mal<sup>2</sup>*.

---

En *[El curioso origen de la palabra "minga"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22569/12637)* nos sorprendió que el origen de la voz estuviera en el nombre propio "Dominga". Tras una consulta a la RAE, su respuesta fue que "los nombres propios de mujer no son infrecuentes en los diversos países para designar los pechos femeninos (*domingas*, *lolas*, *margaritas*...), pero no parecen constar para el caso de los genitales masculinos", y remitieron la consulta al Instituto de Lexicografía para su estudio.

La actualización de 2019 (versión 23.3) ha tenido en cuenta nuestra sugerencia y ha actualizado la etimología de *minga*, apareciendo ahora como `Quizá der. del lat.`*`mingĕre`*`'orinar'`.

---

Tras llevar a cabo una investigación sobre la [etimología y origen de la palabra *horchata*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NyEeGCh), y viendo que la respuesta obtuvo una buena aceptación, decidí enviar a la RAE una copia de la misma para que tengan a bien considerar la teoría propuesta.

Resumiendo: la palabra *horchata* parece casi seguro que proviene (o, al menos, está influenciada) por la palabra latina *hordeata*, pero actualmente se considera que la evolución vino influenciada por el mozárabe. Sin embargo, no hay registros de la palabra *horchata* en español antes del siglo XVIII y el mozárabe se considera lengua muerta desde el siglo XIII. Se propone por tanto que pudo ser una derivación del francés medio *orgeat* (siglos XV-XVI), influenciada por el italiano *orzata* (siglos XVI-XVII) o la propia palabra latina *hordeata*, que dieron lugar a la aparición de registros hacia 1700 tanto de *orchata* como de *horchata* en español.

La actualización de 2021 (versión 23.5) ha tenido en cuenta nuestra sugerencia y ha actualizado la etimología de *horchata*, apareciendo ahora como `Del valenciano`*`orxata,`*`y este del it.`*`orzata,`*`de`*`orzo`*`'cebada' y`*`-ata`*`'-ada'.`

Comment: Gracias, @Charlie, por añadirlo y olé por conseguir el cambio. Son cosas bonitas (y dulces, siendo la horchata :D)

Answer (score 0):

En *[Origen, significado y uso actual de "marta"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30793/12637)* descubrimos que la acepción de "marta" como "mujer aprovechada" quedaba poco clara, al no saberse a qué significado de "aprovechada" hacía referencia. La RAE admitió esta carencia y propuso al Instituto de Lexicografía su estudio para que añadieran una glosa explicando a qué acepción se refiere.

Answer (score 0):

En *[¿Deben las definiciones del DLE ser autosuficientes?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24459/12637)* la RAE admitió que, efectivamente, las definiciones del diccionario deben serlo, haciendo que la acepción 4 de *solfa* sea incorrecta. La RAE afirmó que subsanarían el error lo antes posible.

Answer (score 0):

Tras observar en [Is there an official list of Spanish onomatopoeia?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22844/is-there-an-official-list-of-spanish-onomatopoeia/22846#22846) que no se recoge ninguna onomatopeya como "buaj" o "puaj" para expresar asco, propuse a la RAE la inclusión de "puaj", citando como ejemplos de uso [el que recoge el CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=230919%5C017%5CC000O23092019173224652.1028.1024&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20puaj%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0) así como [el que recoge el Fichero](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_P/LETRA_P_PDF/PUAJ/00001052.pdf) (el cual, por cierto, apunta a un boletín interno de la propia Academia).

Answer (score 0):

Redactando la respuesta para ["Papa-anjo" - persona en una relación con alguien más joven](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23912/papa-anjo-persona-en-una-relaci%c3%b3n-con-alguien-m%c3%a1s-joven/23913#23913) me sorprendí de que el DLE no recogiera la palabra *asaltacunas* (palabra que además ya se había usado en anteriores ocasiones en el sitio; véase [Is there a translation for "cougar"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1392/is-there-a-translation-for-cougar)), así que propuse su inclusión.

Comment: Si existe _[asaltabancos](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3udT03c)_, ¿por qué no _asaltacunas_? :-)

Answer (score 0):

A raíz de dos recomendaciones de Fundéu [aparentemente](https://www.fundeu.es/dudas/palabra-clave/guta/) [contradictorias](https://www.fundeu.es/dudas/palabra-clave/sharia/), decidimos preguntarle a la RAE el porqué de la diferencia de criterios. En sus respuestas en Twitter indicaron que estaban reconsiderando el haber registrado *sharía* en el diccionario, así con tilde.

Quizá no fuera a raíz de nuestro tuit, o quizá sí...

Answer (score 0):

Tras leer [este comentario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31604/translation-golf-xlviii-were-sorry-to-see-you-go/31641?noredirect=1#comment56508_31641) de VeAqui y comprobar por mí mismo que la expresión "ajo y agua" no está recogida en el DLE, he solicitado su inclusión.

> La Unidad Interactiva del DRAE se complace en comunicarle que su
>   mensaje acaba de ser recibido.
>
> **Palabra**: *"ajo y agua"*
>   **Propuesta**: *La expresión "ajo y agua" como acortamiento de "a joderse y aguantarse" es de uso relativamente común en registro coloquial. El CORPES XXI recoge su uso desde 2004, y la propia Academia a través de su cuenta de Twitter ha validado el
>   significado: véase [https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/774198421326589952]. Sin
>   embargo, tal significado (que no es literal y por tanto es recomendable recogerlo en el DLE) no aparece ni bajo el epígrafe de "ajo" ni bajo el de "agua". Propongo su inclusión, en principio bajo el primero de ellos ("ajo") según lo habitual.*
>
> La propuesta o sugerencia que nos envía referente a una voz o acepción
>   del "Diccionario de la lengua española" será estudiada y valorada para
>   su posible inclusión en la vigésima cuarta edición.

Answer (score 0):

En *[¿Cómo recoge el diccionario el uso de "entrar" en "Entrarle a una chica"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27716)* nos percatamos de que en el DLE faltaba la acepción correspondiente al verbo *entrar* para "entrarle a alguien" en el sentido de "iniciar una conversación con alguien".

La RAE [nos ha reconocido](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32430/12637) que, efectivamente, esa acepción falta en el DLE (aunque sí que aparece en otros diccionarios, como el *Diccionario del estudiante*), y nos confirma que el Instituto de lexicografía va a estudiar su inclusión en el DLE.