# ¡Cumplimos 10 años!

Tags: discusión

El 15 de noviembre de 2021, Spanish Language Stack Exchange cumple 10 años. SE está preparando una publicación en el blog mencionando a todos los sitios que cumplen 10 años en la segunda mitad de 2021, incluido el nuestro. Sería similar a [esta publicación](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/19/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old/) que hicieron el semestre pasado.

Para esta publicación, necesitan nuestra ayuda con la descripción del sitio. He escrito el siguiente texto (no he podido dedicar mucho tiempo a buscar los mejores ejemplos) y **me gustaría recibir sugerencias para mejorarlo**:

> A site for learners and enthusiasts of the Spanish language. We [clarify the basic rules](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/661/24236), the [differences between the regional variants](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/7085/24236) and research the [origin of some obscure words](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3237/24236).

Además, tenemos la posibilidad de tener un *banner* (como [este](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZSr6.png), encima de las "hot network questions") en todas las páginas del sitio, indicando que estamos celebrando nuestro décimo aniversario e incluyendo opcionalmente un enlace a uno de nuestros posts en Meta. **Si alguien está en contra o a favor de tener este banner, por favor que lo indique. También pido sugerencias sobre cuál de nuestros posts en Meta podría ser un buen candidato para ser enlazado en este banner**.

Comment: Sería interesante comparar la salud con lo que expusimos en [¡Cumplimos 5 años en beta!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2547/1674).

Comment: Por mi parte, viendo que nadie responde, personalmente me gustaría ver el banner en nuestro sitio. Un artículo como el que menciona @fedorqui'SOstopharming' sobre el estado de salud del sitio podría estar bien, pero también tenemos por ahí una pregunta en Meta con [los logros principales del sitio](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2940/12637) (no son muchos, pero haberlos haylos)

Comment: If the linked Meta post is intended to also interest people from outside Hispanic cultures then I would suggest one in English might be better than the suggestion from  @Charlie

Comment: The three questions linked by wimi in the suggested excerpt look good to me.

Comment: Ahora que ya se está añadido [el banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOvsK.png), ¿se supone que debía tener enlace a alguna página?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' lo hemos dejado sin enlace, porque no había mucho consenso sobre la página a enlazar y el estado de salud es claramente peor que hace 5 años.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' sería más bien un ejercicio de masoquismo. Y fútil. Los problemas de participación los llevamos señalando mucho tiempo, pasando por la propuesta de reducir  el número de votos necesarios para reabrir/cerrar preguntas, por la que esperamos casi un año mano sobre mano sin hacer intentos paralelos o adicionales de mejorar la participación. Cuando [insistí tras las elecciones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4399/5481) la respuesta fue "Lo sabemos. Haz un post en Meta con lo que quieras discutir". No creo que nadie se sorprenda de que hayamos llegado a este punto.

Comment: Yo mismo he perdido interés, incluyendo discutir el problema, investigar las causas y/o plantear posibles soluciones. Ahora mi pregunta es si quedan miembros de la comunidad con ganas suficientes como para cambiar algo y sobre todo, líderes de pensamiento para dirigir el cambio. Viendo como ha decaído el sitio y que el problema es obvio pero que no se trata, entiendo que no los hay. De nada sirven las mejores ideas si no hay miembros de la comunidad dispuestos a llevarlas a cabo. Hemos perdido en participación incluyendo liderazgo y motivación. Nadie puede decir que no se avisó ni se vio venir